# Java ExecutorService heap space problems

Tags: java, multithreading, exception, executorservice

I hava a Java mulithreading question. I have the following worker class:

```
public class ThreadWorker implements Runnable {

    //some code in here

    public void run(){
      // invokes some recursion method in the ThreadWorker itself,
      // which will stop eventually
    {
}
```

To work with threads I'm using an `ExecutorService`:

```
public static int THREAD_NUMBER = 4;
public static ExecutorServide es = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(THREAD_NUMBER);
```

Adding instances of `ThreadWroker` class happens here:

```
public void recursiveMethod(Arraylist<Integers> elements, MyClass data){
     if (elements.size() == 0 && data.qualifies()){
         ThreadWorker tw = new ThreadWorker(data);
         es.execute(tw);
         return;
     }



     for (int i=0; i< elements.size(); i++){
          // some code to prevent my problem
          MyClass data1 = new MyClass(data);
          MyClass data2 = new MyClass(data); 
          ArrayList<Integer> newElements = (ArrayList<Integer>)elements.clone();
          data1.update(elements.get(i));
          data2.update(-1 * elements.get(i));
          newElements.remove(i);
          recursiveMethod(newElements, data1);
          recursiveMethod(newElements, data2);     
     {    
}
```

The problem is that the depth of the recursion tree is quite big, so as it's width, so a lot of `ThreadWorkers` are added to the `ExecutorService`, so after some time on the big input a get

```
Exception in thread "pool-1-thread-2" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

which is caused, as I think because of a ginormous number of `ThreadWorkers` i'm adding to `ExecutorSirvice` to be executed, so it runs out of memory. Every `ThreadWorker` takes about 40 Mb of RAM for all it needs.

Is there a method to get how many threads (instances of classes implementing runnable interface) have been added to `ExecutorService`? So I can add it in the shown above code (int the " // some code to prevent my problem"), as

```
while ("number of threads in the ExecutorService" > 10){
    Thread.sleep(10000);
}
```

so I won't go to deep or to broad with my recursion and prevent those exception-throwing situations.

Sincerely, Sergey Aganezov jr.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about creating a [ThreadPoolExecutor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html) backed by a `BlockingQueue` using [ThreadPoolExecutor.CallerRunsPolicy](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.CallerRunsPolicy.html).

This way, when there are no worker threads available to run a task on, the main thread (which is adding the new jobs) runs the task itself, which prevents any more jobs from being added.

There are more details on the constructor options for [ThreadPoolExecutor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html) on its Javadoc page.

Comment: Create 


`TreadPoolExecutor es = new ThreadPoolExecutor(4, 4, 10000, TimUnit.MILLISECONDS, new ArrayBlockingQueue<Runnable>(10));`

 and then set the rejectedHandler to it 
`es.setRejectedExecutionHandler(new ThreadPoolExecutor.CallerRunsPolicy());`.

After this, if I understand it right, it'll handle my problem, since once number of running threads reaches 4 and number of queued threads reaches 10 the next added task will be rejected and performed it the main thread, stopping all other activity in it.

Answer (score 1):

I think your case is a good match for the "fork-join" framework of the Java JDK. (Google for that keyword.)

Fork-Join helps you to trim down the number of jobs in your queue by delaying the "split" as far as possible.

You have to reformulate your code into that philosophy though.