# reading lots of messages from amazon sqs

Tags: java, multithreading, amazon-sqs

I am trying to read from an SQS queue with a bunch of messages on it (~2mil) but am running in to trouble with how to setup the threading model to get decent performance.

I tried this:

```
            ExecutorService es = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(16);
            //getApproximateNumberOfMessages() - uses sqs regular (not async) client to call getQueueAttributes, etc
            final AtomicInteger approximateNumberOfMessages = new AtomicInteger(getApproximateNumberOfMessages());
            while(approximateNumberOfMessages.get() > 0) {
                es.execute(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        //getMessages uses sqs regular (not async) client to call receiveMessage()
                        List<Message> messages = getMessages();
                        for (Message message : messages) {
                            handleSingleMessage(message);
                        }
                        approximateNumberOfMessages.decrementAndGet();
                    }
                });
            }
```

However, I quickly get out of memory exceptions. I tried switching to `ThreadPoolExecutor` as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10060601/27657), but when I do that the process seems to just lock up.

Is there a way to process the messages asynchronously without running out of memory?

Comment: I had issues trying to add objects to an SQS queue using a `ThreadPool`. The issue was caused because a process got a lock on the SQS Metrics being collected which meant that no other threads could access it. Perhaps it could be a similar issue.

Comment: What about moving the while loop into the run() method? This way you just call execute() 16 times and have running 16 threads as you wanted.